# Preencher table com dados do banco, via Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, pdo, requisição

Eu estou muito confuso.
Estou a criar uma aplicação com PHP e PDO. Tenho uma página onde está uma table com os dados do meu banco. De início, ele já faz a consulta no banco e armazena o resultado em `$result`  para popular a minha table:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('autenticacao/verifica.php');
include('class/DiagnosticoModel.php');

$consulta = new DiagnosticoModel();

$result = $consulta->select();

?>
```

Minha table:

```
<div class="card-body table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr class="table-cs">
                                                    <th>Ticket</th>
                                                    <th>Solicitante</th>  
                                                    <th>Data Início</th>
                                                    <th>Data de entrega</th>
                                                    <th>Status</th>
                                                    <th>Observação</th>
                                                    <th>Ação</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <?php
                                                    foreach ($result as $chave => $valor) { ?>
                                                        <td><?php echo $valor['ticket'] ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php 
                                                        if ($valor['data_inicio'] != 0) {
                                                            echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($valor['data_inicio'])) ;
                                                        }
                                                        ?></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <?php 
                                                        if ($valor['data_termino'] != 0) {
                                                            echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($valor['data_termino'])); }?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $valor['status'] ?></td>
                                                        <td style="width:300px"><?php echo $valor['observacao'] ?></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div class="btn-group">
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-cs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                                    <i class="fas fa-cogs"></i>

                                                                </button>
                                                                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                                                    <button name="btn-atualizar" class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-atualizar<?echo $valor['iddiagnostico'];?>">Atualizar</button>
                                                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                                                    <button name="btn-visualizar" class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-visualizar<?echo $valor['iddiagnostico'];?>">Visualizar Solicitação</button>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                </tr>
```

Aí assim, eu criei 2 botões, 1 para atualizar e outro para listar dados da linha selecionada.
Os botões abrem modais com as informações, e aí para atualizar, eu faço uma nova consulta ao banco, só que ele não atualiza na mesma hora a tabela, por isso gostaria de utilizar o Ajax...

Aí a minha dúvida. Eu preciso excluir essa parte inicial do PHP que faz a consulta e traz os dados pra tabela? Pra fazer isso com ajax? E se sim, como eu posso fazer, já que vi que normalmente faz assim:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: '<?php echo "teste"; ?>',
        success: function(r) {
         $('body').html(r);
    }
});
```

(Peguei esse código da internet)
Nessa parte da "DATA", são os dados que eu passo para fazer alguma pesquisa, alguma atualização, mas como eu não tenho parâmetro, eu só quero fazer a requisição e receber os dados, eu preciso preencher esse "data"? E preciso de alguma outra página php auxiliar, para colocar na URL? Pois gostaria de fazer tudo nessa mesma página.

Não sei se deu pra entender a minha dúvida, sou um pouco leigo com isso de Js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom pelo que entendi você tem uma pagina que já carrega os dados, sincronamente, em backend com php e após carregados você quer atualiza-los conforme descrição do usuário.

Você deve definir como quer fazer isso, se for sincronamente precisará retornar outra pagina php com os dados atualizados, pois você não está usando MVC (Model,View,Controller), não entrarei em detalhes sobre isso mas depois estude sobre.

Neste caso, sim sua melhor solução é usar o AJAX para fazer a requisição assíncrona.
no campo data na verdade são os dados que você quer enviar para o servidor e no campo sucess são os dados retornados do servidor, que após retornados devem ser trabalhados de forma que altere o DOM.

Basicamente você tem que montar uma requisição para o seu servidor e após a resposta alterar o DOM de maneira que encaixe os dados onde você quer. Vou passar alguns links para que você entenda melhor sobre requisições assincronas, jquery e DOM.

https://www.devmedia.com.br/ajax-com-jquery-trabalhando-com-requisicoes-assincronas/37141
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-ajax-with-jquery--cms-25126
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp
https://spigandoeaprendendo.wordpress.com/2014/03/06/jquery-introducao-a-manipulacao-do-dom-pegando-e-atribuindo-conteudo-text-html-and-val/
https://eufacoprogramas.com/jquery-principais-comandos-para-manipulacao-do-dom/

Comment: Muito obrigado! Ajudou bastante, irei ver os links. :)